# How does "would" work in the following sentences?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, modal-verbs

How does "would" work in the following sentences? Is "would" tentative or hypothetical situation here?

- *Any advice that you give **would** be appreciated.*

-Regarding the "Glorious is God" example. The term for this **would** be copular inversion (the inflected form of "to be" is the copula).

Comment: Please note from the excerpt of the _meaning in context_ tag: **"A SPECIFIC CONCERN must be emphasized."** Please edit your question to include your concern(s).

Comment: It's the subjunctive.  If you want a more detailed answer, you'll need to clarify what exactly you don't understand about it.

Comment: @Kevin is "would" tentative or hypothetical situation here?

Comment: This is the modal remoteness use of "would", more specifically the tentative use. It expresses a weaker less assured meaning than "will", often more diffident or polite.